# Why use {} instead of new Object() and use [] instead of new Array() and true/false instead of new Boolean()?

Tags: javascript

Many people say that you should avoid new Object, new Array()and instead use {}. [], and true/false.

What are the benefits of using the literal constructs to get a  new instance of an Object or Array rather than using new?   I konw that Crockford doesn't like new but is that the main argument?

Comment: `new Boolean(true)` is not equivalent to `true`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The advantages of object and array literals over using the respective constructors are:

- Shorter and more readable
- Safer: literals will still work when the `Array` or `Object` constructors have been overridden
- Possibly faster, though it's unlikely to be a major consideration (any bottlenecks will almost certainly originate elsewhere in code)

In the case of arrays, there's an additional advantage of a literal: it's impossible to create an array with a single member using the `Array` constructor alone. For example, `[3]` will create an array with one element which is the number 3, while `new Array(3)` creates an array of length 3.

**Update: the following paragraph is no longer relevant now the question has been edited.**

Regarding Booleans, you seem to have a misconception: `new Boolean(false)` is not the same as `false`. The `Boolean()` constructor creates a Boolean object whereas `false` and `true` are Boolean primitives. In fact, `new Boolean(false)` evaluates to `true` when coerced into a Boolean in, for example, an `if` statement. In short, there's very rarely a reason to use the `Boolean()` constructor. Use `true` and `false` instead. Similarly, other primitives such as strings and numbers have corresponding `String()` and `Number()` constructors that produce `String` and `Number` objects that are different to primitive strings and numbers and should generally be avoided.

Comment: Edited the original questions to remove the incorrect true/false instead of new Boolean() statement.

Comment: @Paul: I'll leave the Boolean stuff in my answer: it's still useful information.

Comment: Some interesting performance notes: Using `new Object()` and `new Array()` seems to actually be faster in newer browsers than declaring with literals like `{}` and `[]`. (see [this](http://jsperf.com/array-creation-blank), [this](http://jsperf.com/array-creation-perf), and [this](http://jsperf.com/object-performance)).

Comment: One the main reasons not to use `new Array()` is because of the ambiguity when passing a single argument. The reasons you mentioned are valid but aren't major problems

Comment: @JuanMendes Can you please explain your comment with an example?

Comment: @Chad Actually I found all 3 test are faster for the literals. (Using Chrome v47)

Comment: @Ofear,  `new Array(1,2,3)` retuns `[1,2,3]` but `new Array(1)`  returns `[undefined]`;

Comment: @Ofear Your comparing performance in your modern browser vs a post I did 2 years ago? I'm sure things have changed.

Comment: hehe, I didn't look on the date it was posted. :)

Comment: any idea how to modify array literals constructor?

Answer (score 4):

For example, if you want to do this:

```
{name:"bla",address:"address"}
```

the new Object() way would be:

```
var o = new Object();
o.name="bla";
o.address="address";
```

The first one is much shorter. And I think that it would be faster in many browsers, too ([jsperf testcase](http://jsperf.com/object-performance)).

Comment: Faster, yes. Several years ago I tried the `new Array()` method then added all the values with `arr.push()` - there were thousands of values to add (I had no life =_= ) and it was slow as... fudge. Just putting all the values insie the array constructor `new Array(val1,val2,val3...)` was hugely faster!

Comment: @Kolink - That's likely because you were calling `.push()`. The question here is more about constructor `new Array(val1,val2,val3...)` vs literal `[val1,val2,val3...]`

Comment: `new Object()` and `new Array()` are a lot faster when you need to construct a ton of them and then set/append data very often. In a parser/decoder there's a noticeable speed gain when using them.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's mostly about succinctness.

Why write `new Array()` when you can write `[]`, or `new Object()` when you can write `{}`?

Also `new Boolean()` is entirely redundant. A boolean is always going to need to be either true or false, so you should definitely use the built in constants for that.

Comment: `new Boolean(true)` is worse than redundant, it's different to the primitive `true`. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases an [object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500130/javascript-object-literals) or array literal is sufficient and easier to use. You can even call or apply prototype methods (e.g. [].prototype.slice.call(someObj)) It's mostly [faster](http://jsperf.com/literal-vs-constructor-array) too. 
You'll may want to notice that {} and []‘s constructor cannot be overwritten and that 
`Object` and `Array` are constructors where {} and [] are instances.

Comment: I've run the jsperf test you link to and the literals are the slowest of the three (_on my machine_). I'm guessing that's down to Firefox 3.6.12

Comment: I ran the tests in Chrome, where using literals was faster. If you scroll down on the jsperf page there are some extra results from 'browserscope'

Answer (score 0):

One reason not yet mentioned is the ambiguity when passing parameters to the Array constructor. It's all specified behavior, it's just quirky.

```
new Array(1,2,3); // [1,2,3], that's OK
new Array(1); // [undefined], some may expect to get [1] instead
```

> A JavaScript array is initialized with the given elements, except in the case where a single argument is passed to the Array constructor and that argument is a number. (See below.) Note that this special case only applies to JavaScript arrays created with the Array constructor, not array literals created with the bracket syntax. 
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Syntax