# Array read problem for map of vectors of strings in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie in JS. Here is my code and I believe it should work... but it doesn't.

```
var pop = new Array();
pop['la'] = new Array('nt','gb','te');
pop['sa'] = new Array('nt','gb');
pop['ha'] = new Array('pc','pa');
var _ecpop="la";

for (var i = 0; i < pop[_ecpop].length; i++)
{
    document.write(pop[_ecpop][i]);
}
```

I just do not know any alternate way to have a map of vectors of a string.

Thanks,

Amir.

Comment: Please format the code, by indenting it with 4 spaces. The preview below the input should help you with the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an Array, but a Javascript Object, containing Arrays in it's properties. You can use Object and Array [literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Literals) for that. The advantage is that your code looks much cleaner. There are seldom reasons to use `new Array` or `new Object` in javascript code (see for example [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292048/why-use-instead-of-new-object-and-use-instead-of-new-array-and-true-fal)).

```
var pop = {
  la: ['nt','gb','te'],
  sa: ['nt','gb'],
  ha: ['pc','pa']
}
```

now you can use

```
for (var i = 0; i < pop.la.length; i++) { 
 console.log(pop.la[i]);
}
```

if a property label is stored in a variable (like you _ecpop), you can use [bracket notiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets) to retrieve it's value:

```
var laArr = pop[_ecpop];
for (var i = 0; i < laArr.length; i++) { 
 console.log(laArr[i]);
}
```

The other way around you can assign a label to an Object:

```
var _ecpop = 'la';
pop[_ecpop] = ['nt','gb','te'];
```

`document.write` is not the preferred way to put things on your page. It's better and just as easy to use some element with an id, and write output to it using `innerHTML`, for example

```
document.getElementById('myOutput').innerHTML = '[some output here]';
```

Comment: The problem is _ecpop is a string that I got from URL query string.. I was thinking about this way... but then I do not know how to make it work...

Comment: then you could us pop[_ecpop], or assign pop[_ecpop] to a variable to loop further (`var laArr = pop[_ecpop]; for (var i=0; i<laArr.length ... etc`) => see edit

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, an array can only have numeric indexes, if you want to use textual indexes, you should use object instead.

```
var pop = new Object();
```

or

```
var pop = {};
```

and then:

```
pop['la'] = new Array('nt','gb','te');
```

However, as an object is not an array, it has no length member, but just as an array you can use the [for..in](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for_in.asp) to go through all of its values.

Using document.write is not a good choice as it only works during the document loading, not after it. Try to use text nodes or innerhtml instead.

Comment: I realized if I only change var pop = new Array(); to var pop = {}; it works!