# How can I checked checkbox, if I have an array of values?

Tags: jquery, arrays, checkbox, checked

I have the folowing inptuts!

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" value="5" />
```

After using jQuery I want my result to look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" checked />
<input type="checkbox" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" value="3" checked  />
<input type="checkbox" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" value="5" checked />
```

I use following code, but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var str = '1,3,5';
    var temp = new Array();
    temp = str.split(",");
    for (a in temp ) {
        //$('.check').valueOf().checked;
        $('.check').val(append(temp[a])).checked;
        //$('#c').append();
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Description

You can loop through your array using `for(i=0;i!=temp.length;i++)` and use the attribute selector to get the right checkbox.

Check out my sample and this  [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/2W46M/)

#### Sample

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var str = '1,3,5';
    var temp = new Array();
    temp = str.split(",");
    for (i=0; i!=temp.length;i++) {
        var checkbox = $("input[type='checkbox'][value='"+temp[i]+"']");
        checkbox.attr("checked","checked");
    }
});
```

#### More Information

- [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/2W46M/)
- [jQuery - Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [jQuery - .attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: I would [avoid using `new Array`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292048/why-use-instead-of-new-object-and-use-instead-of-new-array-and-true-fa)

Comment: +1 to this, i had almost the identical solution written in my jsfiddle. Curse you, time!

Answer (score 1):

I must ask, how exactly do you expect that to work? For starters you're calling for elements with the class name `check`, which none of your elements have, then you're just having a statement without any assignment or anything... You're also creating an array that just gets thrown away because `split` creates a new array. Further, instead of your string splitting, just something like `var temp = [1,3,5];` would work fine... And finally you use `for...in` on an array, which is bad because arrays have properties beside their keys (such as `length` and several methods)...

Anyway, what you need is something more like:

```
(function() {
    var elms = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]'), l = qsa.length, i;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
        elms[i].checked = (elms[i].value % 2 == 1);
    }
})();
```

Comment: This is reliant on him only ever wanting odd numbers to be checked, isn't it? Seems sort of risky.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
        if( $(this).index() % 2 == 0 ){
            $(this).attr('checked','checked');
        }
     });
});
```

You can play around with the fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/EuXQF/

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var array = "1,3,5,2";
    check_value(array);
});
    function check_value(val){
        var array = val.split(",");
        for (i=0;i<array.length;i++){
             //alert(array[i]);

             $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
                if( $(this).val() == array[i]){
                    $(this).attr('checked','checked');
                }
             });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Best solution ever! hope it help u.!

Comment: your post is a little bit strange, thank, if you want help. But it looks like a spam. The question has been open 4 years ago. There was already some good answer. And you don't need to comment your answer in that way. I encourage you to answer the hot question with no accepted answer. When you get used to stack overflow, don't hesitate to answer any question that you think it's needed.