# For loop withoit indexes javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I want to display an array without showing of indexes. The for loop returns the array indexes which is not showing in usual declaration.
I want to send an array like `[1,2,3 ...]` but after retrieving from for loop, I haven't the above format. How can I store my values as above.

```
var a = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
    a[i] = i;
};
console.log(a);
```

Outputs:

```
[1: 1, 2: 2 ...]
```

Desired output:

```
[1,2,3]// same as console.log([1,2,3])
```

Comment: The resulted array is correct (except it holds `undefined` at the first index). The output in the console is just formatted in a different way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you start your array with `1` index, making initial `0` position being empty (so called "hole" in array). Basically you treat array as normal object (which you can do of course but it defeats the purpose of array structure) - and because of this browser `console.log` decides to shows you keys, as it thinks that you want to see object keys as well as its values.

You need to `push` values to array:

```
var a = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
    a.push(i);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Array indices start at zero, your loop starts at 1, with index 0 missing you have a sparse array that's why you get that output, you can use push to add values to an array without using the index.

```
var a = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
    a.push(i);
};
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have to disagree with the answers provided here. The best way to do something like this is:

```
var a = new Array(7);
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i] = i + 1;
}
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Can you please explain, why would this be the best way? This doesn't even put the numbers OP needs to the array.

Comment: Because this way allocates the required size in one go, while creating a 0-length array and increasing it size gradually will most likely require re-allocating memory blocks multiple times (depends on the final size of the array).

Comment: I'm appreciating your explanation. Thanks.

Comment: Afaik defining an empty array using `[]` is preferred nowadays. `new Array()` should be avoided because of some inconsistencies of it when using arguments. Looks like you've fixed the content issue though.

Comment: @Teemu Yes, I did fix the content, thanks to your comment. What inconsistencies are there with `new Array(size)`?

Comment: [A result of a quick-search](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4292494/1169519). What is not actually told in that answer (or rather is slightly erranously implemented), is that you can't create an array  containing a single number member by using `new` operator. That's an inconsistency, since you can create an array with two or more numbers ... About the memory allocation, JS doesn't have real arrays, they are just objects.

Comment: @Teemu I don't really understand how that is an inconsistency, seems to me like the behavior is perfectly documented and predictable. Either way, using the `Array` constructor when the array literal syntax could be used for the same effect seems pointless to me (unless the `Array` constructor is shown to be faster). The point here is that the `Array` constructor can allocated the required memory block at once, instead of requiring multiple allocations – something that can hurt performance exponentially.

Comment: If a guy who's involved in developing JavaScript language [recommends `[]`](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) (see "Bonus Suggestions" at the near of the end of the article), I doubt using it would cause any performance problems.

Comment: @Teemu Here's a simple test: http://jsperf.com/array-growth-vs-pre-allocation. See for yourself the performance benefits.

Comment: Looks like you're testing `a.push()` against `a[i] = i` ... You can use a regular assignment with `a = []` as well.

Comment: @Teemu That's because the Array literal syntax does not allow you to set the size of the array without providing the elements themselves directly in the code – which is exactly the advantage of the `Array` constructor and the reason why I suggested using it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is making each index equal to `i`, so use it this way

```
var a = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
a.push(i);
};
console.log(a);
```