# Faster Implementation of C++ like Map in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I am only a beginner in javascript. I needed something similar to C++ map. So, I used this -

```
var map = new Object();
map['key'] = 'value';
```

Although it worked fine, I was unhappy with the performance. It takes a long time when I tested it with a data set of about 100000 entry. Can you suggest a better solution to improve the performance?

Comment: Did you compare the performance with [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)?

Comment: I am not sure about javascript map performance. I am in search of something like C++ map in comparison with the performance.

Comment: How do you define "a long time"? Setting or retrieving?

Comment: tested what exactly? Question is seriously lacking detail

Comment: This question is not about "time-complexity".

Comment: javascript is a high level language and does have speed issues with large quantities of data, particularly if you're referring to js in the browser, as opposed to server-side JS.  Much of that is your browser's fault I'm sorry to say.

Comment: It takes about 1 minute on my pc. Same code runs for less than 1 second on C++

Comment: what takes 5 minutes? you aren't providing a [mcve]

Comment: Comparing the performance of Javascript to C++ is like comparing a Smart Car to a Maserati.

Comment: If it takes one minute, you're doing something seriously wrong. It should take less than a hundred milliseconds.

Comment: What runs about 5 seconds? 
  var map = {};
     for(var x =0; x< 100000; x++){
       map['value'+x] = Math.random();
     }

runs 200ms in console.

Comment: @VladimirM That "benchmark" is dominated by the time for `Math.random()`.

Comment: @torazaburo yes. and it is still only 200ms

Comment: I have some other functions to add some complexity though. But the difference is very clear.

Comment: If you want C++ performance, then write in C++. In this case, what you see is what you get.

Comment: @t.niese `Map` is unlikely to be faster. Actually, it's most likely 3-4 times slower.

Comment: C++ application compiles and runs native. JS, even compiles by the engine, still runs by that engine within a sandbox. On top of that, C++ may even optimize for multi-thread/multi-processor. Javascript is a single-threaded. But, all above doesn't also mean that your code is optimal. Who knows, may be you can make use of web workers to run your calculations in parallel.

Comment: I'd like to thank the OP for making a post which encouraged so many interesting discussions

Comment: BTW, just a wild guess... does your methods by any chance produce any output on the page, while doing the calculations. If you are inserting 100000 DOM elements, then you may very well get into minutes.

Comment: I think the difference comes from the internal data structure and implementation of C++ map. And I was expecting some better javascript implementation to make it fast enough.

Comment: can show your code? Honestly, 100k of simple data items is not such a big  deal.

Comment: [code](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23247691/)

Comment: sorry, I misjudged it. It runs for approximately 20 seconds on my pc

Comment: **What** runs for 20 seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a shot at what you're seeing.  It sounds like you're a C++ guy who's new to JS, so I'm going to walk you through some of the basics and we'll wrap up with a nice demo.

1)  Map is not the term for what you're doing.

Using the word map is confusing some people here because in JS, [map is actually a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on an array that you can use to change the shape of it's data.  What you're doing instead is creating an Object.  Javascript objects are dynamic, and so adding properties on the fly is completely reasonable, and that's the premise of your situation.  You want to add lots of properties to a dynamic object.

2) Without an example, your question is vague

It's hard to decipher what is taking "a long time" to run on your machine.  Is this server-side JS or client-side?  Have you used the cool new multi-core stuff?  Are you creating 100,000 objects or simply adding 100,000 properties to a single object?  As a C++ guy, you should know better than to be so vague.  Creating an object allocates memory, and everyone in C++ knows that memory allocation is heavy.  So that one bit of information can make a huge difference.

3) The speed of JS is slower than C++

Period.  C++ is a lower level language.  In order to do things automatically for you (like allocating memory) higher level languages are inherently slower.  This is not to mention the overhead imposed by your browser.

4) Most optimizations are out of your hands

Unless you're working in binary (note: not assembly, binary) the commands you're working with are interpreted by software.  That interpreter's speed is not something you can make a huge impact on.  As a lightweight example, client-side JS is affected by the speed of the browser, the speed of the user's processor, the speed of the user AND server's networks in unison, the number of requests, lag time for AJAX calls, and even the number of other things the user is doing on their computer at a given time.

5) It's not *that* slow.  Let's look at some real data points.

Below you'll see that it's less that 1/10th of a second (on my machine atm) to add 100,000 properties to one object, and only slightly slower (still less than 1/10 of a second) to create 100,000 objects and add 1 property to each.

We up the time (almost 2/10 of a second) a lot by logging it to the console, but even that isn't our fault, or something you should be encountering in optimized code.

**WARNING, RUNNING THIS CODE SNIPPET WILL HANG YOUR BROWSER FOR A FEW SECONDS**

```js
var start = new Date().getTime();
var obj1 = {};
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
  obj1[i.toString()] = 'test';
}
var end = new Date().getTime();
var time1 = end - start;
console.log(obj1);
end = new Date().getTime();
var time2 = end - start;

start = new Date().getTime();
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
  var obj2 = {};
  obj2[i.toString()] = 'test';
}
end = new Date().getTime();
var time3 = end - start
console.log(time1);
console.log(time2);
console.log(time3);
```

Comment: By not wrapping these in functions, are you not preventing JIT-style optimizations?

Comment: I was not trying to build a benchmark, because benchmarks are both hard to do, and rarely accurate.  I was merely creating actual data points for our OP to look at.  I suspect his code looks nothing like mine anyway, so just seeing some code may help him.

Comment: Not gonna lie, when I clicked _Run code snippet_ I was not expecting my browser to hang ;) 45 / 271 / 84

Answer (score -2):

This is the same:

```
var map = {};
map.key = 'value';
```

Comment: And therefore...what?

Comment: Good practices tell us this way have a better performance

Comment: No difference in performance whatsoever.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292048/why-use-instead-of-new-object-and-use-instead-of-new-array-and-true-fa

Comment: The post you quote says "**possibly** faster". But in this case that statement is being executed only once, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @torazaburo that is an assumption.  The OP didn't specify whether he was creating 100,000 objects or not.

Comment: If you don't know, then ask him in a comment instead of making your own assumption.

Comment: By the way, he said "**a** data set of about 100000 **entries**". Note the word "**a**", which refers to a **single** object.